# Python - Converting json data to a csv format for a specific key

Tags: python, json, csv

I am working on a application and want to extract data from a json file using a key and store it to a csv file for further use.

The sample json data looks something like :

> [ {"Name " : "John","Office":"1st Ave", "Birth date": "1978-01-01"}, {"Name":"Jane","Office": "2nd Ave","Birth date": "1970-01-01"}]

**This is just dummy data**

So far what i did is :

```
with open("input.json") as infile, open('output.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=' ')

    i=0
    for line in infile:
        d = json.loads(line)
        writer.writerows(d[i]['Name'])
        i=i+1
```

but with this code the problem i am face is the csv file looks something like:

> J
>
> o
>
> h
>
> n

that's it instead i want :

> Name
>
> John
>
> Jane

Any idea on why it is happening and how can it be resolved?

**Also :**

i would like to add a label to the csv as 0 as the second column. As in :

> Name    ID
>
> John     0
>
> Jane     0

Comment: May not be relevant but your keys in the input file are not homogeneous : you have 'Name ' (with a final space) and 'Name' (without final spacing)

Comment: Ya as mentioned its just dummy data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would go quite straightforward with `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json('input.json')
df['Name'].to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
df['ID'] = O
df[['Name','ID']].to_csv('output_2.csv', index=False, sep = ' ')
```

As far as I understood 'ID' value always equals 0. Correct?

Comment: yes id is just another column with all entries as 0 in the csv file, but by this code its added to the same column instead of a new column ?

Comment: in the code I define a new column and set value to 0. Then I take a subset of the dataset ('Name', 'ID') and export it to the desired csv file

Answer (score 0):

For each line, your "Name" is not a list.

```
line = '{"Name": "John", "Office": "1st Ave", "Birth date": "1978-01-01"}'

d = json.loads(line)
d['Name'] # "John"
```

You need to create a list of items before `writerows`:

```
names = [json.loads(x)['Name'] for x in lines]
writer.writerows(names)
```